# How to use the first line of the messages for fingerprinting issues in Sentry?

Tags: sentry

On our self-hosted Sentry instance (version 22.7.0), we group our Java issues not by stack trace, but by message, using the following fingerprinting rule:

```
message:"*" -> {{ message }}
```

However, sometimes messages differ in the second line, like so:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_pkey"
  Detail: Key (foo_id)=(1000001) already exists.
```

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_pkey"
  Detail: Key (foo_id)=(1000002) already exists.
```

This creates unnecessarily many distinct issues.

Is there a way to adjust the rule, such that only the first line of the error message is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible - I am not sure how you use this in your app but we also have client-side fingerprinting which might help
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/usage/sdk-fingerprinting/

Comment: That should work. Thanks!